# In an object, how do I add values that only contain an integer?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the values that only contain an integer; however, my code adds the string values as well. I am new to this, so I could not figure out how to do this. The expected value would be `15`

```
const sumMe = {
    hello: 'there',
    you: 8,
    are: 7,
    done: '!'
  };

  let total = 0;
  for (let key in sumMe){     
    total += sumMe[key]
}

console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Number` for it

```
total += Number(sumMe[key]);
```

The runnable code listed below:

```js
const sumMe = {
    hello: 'there',
    you: 8,
    are: 7,
    done: '!'
  };

  let total = 0;
  for (let key in sumMe){
    let val = Number(sumMe[key]);
    if(!!val){//check if it's a valid number
        total += val;
    }
}

console.log(total)
```

Comment: But that will result in the total being `NaN` if any of the values cannot be coerced to numbers

Comment: By a first look, if one of the properties values is `true`, you will add 1 to the total perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript built-in function `isNaN()` to check if the value is a valid number.

```js
const sumMe = {
  hello: "there",
  you: 8,
  are: 7,
  done: "!"
};

let total = 0;

for (let key in sumMe) {
  total = isNaN(sumMe[key]) ? total : total + sumMe[key];
}

console.log(total)
```